# Nested Query Dot Notation or Name Casting

Tags: soql, query, nested

Quick question - I am unable to find any documentation on the dot notation when using nested queries. I assume they are name casting but I was hoping someone could point me in the direct of actual documentation on the difference between:

```
List<Opportunity> lstOpp = [SELECT Id, Name, ( SELECT n.Title FROM Notes n LIMIT 50) FROM Opportunity ];

List<Opportunity> lstOpp = [SELECT Id, Name, ( SELECT Title FROM Notes LIMIT 50) FROM Opportunity ];
```

Is the `n` just to reaffirm for the reader that the Title field belongs to Notes? Or is there actual compute assistance with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [aliases](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_alias.htm) to write shorter queries. The example in the docs say:

> ```
> SELECT count()
> FROM Contact c, c.Account a
> WHERE a.name = 'MyriadPubs'
> ```

Here, we specify `Contact` as `c`, allowing us to write `c.Account` instead of `Contact.Account`; we can then use the alias from `c.Account a` to write `WHERE a.name` instead of `Account.Name`.

There is no performance benefit using the alias, and most of the time, developers ignore this feature.

A more practical example might look like this:

```
SELECT c.Name, a.Name, o.Name
FROM Contact c, c.Account a, a.Owner o
WHERE o.Name = 'Some User'
```

Which is the same as:

```
SELECT Name, Account.Name, Account.Owner.Name
FROM Contact
WHERE Account.Owner.Name = 'Some User'
```

The more parent/child objects you need to query, the more keystrokes you can save. This was especially important historically, because SOQL statements had a limited length. They're still limited, but have been greatly expanded in recent releases.

Comment: makes sense, thank you!